# Stratified OpenLayers Clustering

Tags: openlayers-2, clustering

I have an OpenLayers map with point clustering, but I want to apply a much finer granularity to the data represented in the map.  Specifically, I want to stratify the clusters according to an attribute on the feature (we'll call it 'category').

So, say I have five categories: effectively I need to cluster points only with other points from the same category.  I suppose this could be accomplished with five different layers, but this quickly becomes cumbersome as the number of categories gets large (I have 50+ at the moment).

Has anyone seen anything like this with OpenLayers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked the dev examples ?

- http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster.html
- http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster-threshold.html
- http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster-extended.html

I'm pretty sure you could 'group' them by an attribute.  The last example has good info.

Comment: Funny, I had picked through the first two and somehow dismissed the third.  This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem at all, I knew I had just seen it going through them for other things, I stumbled upon it using the search function on that page. very handy.